# Disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention warning for custom naming convention

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Me and my team have a custom naming convention for some of our variables that are causing eslint to generate warnings. Basically, we have around two hundred objects of the same type which we use throughout our app. To keep things organized, we have given each object an identifier with the following naming convention: `section_page_objectTitle`. This is using a mix of snake_case and camelCase (i.e. `objectTitle`), so eslint throws an error saying:

`Variable name 'section_page_objectTitle' must match one of the following formats: camelCase, PascalCase, UPPER_CASE eslint@typescript-eslint/naming-convention`

We have set up this naming convention so that it is easy to identify where the object is used in the app because each part of the id is divided by "_". If we were to switch `objectTitle` to snake_case to satisfy the eslint rule, then it would be `section_page_object_title` and we would lose that classification.

I am trying to modify the eslint rule to allow for this naming convention, but the [documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention) isn't very clear on how to do this.

The list of values that section can be is small, so I was trying to setup a rule to allow for anything that starts with one of the section names followed by an underscore (`section_`), but I wasn't able to find how to do that.

EDIT: I know that I can just disable that line, but I would prefer not to if possible since we would have to do that for all 200+ objects.

Comment: Do you have `.eslintrc` file or/abnd `"eslintConfig"` section within your `package.json`?  You can use `"rules"` object to modify your linting rules.

Comment: See [this `eslint` docs page](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1). You can add the name of the linting rule and set to `off`, `warn`, or `error`.

Comment: Yes, I have a .eslintrc file, and I know that I can modify the rules. I was looking for some help on how to customize the rule to allow for the naming convention I want.